# prevent yui from adding id automatically

Tags: yui

how to disable yui from adding id to node automatically. like Y.one('#mynode').setHTML('some content');

I want the html looks like

```
<div id="mynode"><div>some content</div></div>
```

however, it shows like

```
<div id="mynode"><div id="yui_3_......">some content</div></div>
```

how I can make it looks like what I want

Answer (score 0):

I had a look and decided it wasn't easily achievable, as this is how YUI works. You'll also find it adds IDs when event handlers fire (all the way up from the element which triggered the event, to the body, which can be confusing.

Can I ask though, why does it matter? Anything which already has an ID won't get it replaced. so it's only elements which had no ID assigned which are affected.